# How to get only one prototype bean in one method invocation?

Tags: java, spring, singleton, prototype

I have a ptototype bean autowired in a singleton bean. To get different bean of the prototype bean, I marked it with proxyMode. Then, the side effect is huge: I always get more than one instances.

Here is my sample code:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Duplicate {
public void serve() {
    log.error("{}", this);
}

public Duplicate get() {
    return this;
}
}
```

and

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Singleton {
@Autowired
private Duplicate d1;

public void serve(){
    Duplicate duplicate = d1.get();
    log.warn("d1 - 0 = {}", duplicate);
    log.warn("d1 - 1 = {}", duplicate);
    duplicate.serve();
}
}
```

and a UT case:

```
@Autowired
private Singleton singleton;
@Test
public void testOnScope(){
    singleton.serve();
}
```

The output is so weired to me:

```
Singleton - d1 - 0 = Duplicate@14f7e21a
Singleton - d1 - 1 = Duplicate@2bd9722
Duplicate - Duplicate@544cd64b
```

The memory addresses are totally different!

How should I modify my code to achieve the goal?

Comment: you shouldn't autowire prototype beans into singleton beans. instead, use bean factory to load bean on-demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use

```
ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS
```

use @Lookup instead.

I post a blog public, but it's in Chinese.
https://www.jianshu.com/p/eee4a785cadc